# Subdomain friendly url redirect on multiple folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I'm setting up a apache server and trying to make friendly url's on my subdomains. This is the current setup of folders in my root folder:

```
mydomain ----\
        |
        | - Folder A (folder_a) --\
        |       |
        |       | - Sub Site A(subfolder) --\
        |       |       | - index from sub folder
        |       |
        |       | index from Folder A
        |
        | - Folder B (folder_a) --\
        |       |
        |       | - Sub Site B(subfolder) --\
        |       |       | - index from sub folder
        |       |
        |       | index from Folder B
        |
        | - Folder C ...
```

So, what does works without any htaccess are these urls:

```
mydomain.com/folder_a/subfolder
mydomain.com/folder_b/subfolder
```

But i'm trying to achieve the following result with some htaccess:

```
subfolder.mydomain/folder_a
subfolder.mydomain/folder_b
```

I tried making this htaccess on root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subfolder\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(.*)$ $1/subfolder/index.php$2 [L]
```

But it gives me an error 500 on apache.

And also this htaccess inside folder_a for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mydomain\.com$
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder_a/subdomain/index.php$1 [L,QSA]
# OR
RewriteRule (.*) http://subdomain.mydomain.com/folder_a/subdomain/index.php$1 [L]
```

And it also gives me error 500.

This is my current virtual host file for these domains:

```
<VirtualHost mydomain.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "W:/mydomaindevteste"
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost subdomain.mydomain.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "W:/mydomaindevteste"
    ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache error

```
[Mon Jan 28 07:54:12.433767 2019] [core:error] [pid 13208:tid 2032] [client 127.0.0.1:49993] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Jan 28 07:54:12.433767 2019] [core:error] [pid 13208:tid 2032] [client 127.0.0.1:49993] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message that is logged to the Apache error log?

Comment: Please add such messages to the question, not to the comment section.